# Canot start a service instance in Virtuoso-opensource

Tags: instance, startup, virtuoso

I can not start virtuoso. I run : `./virtuoso-start.sh` and got the message:

```
Starting Virtuoso instance in [database]
The VDBMS server process terminated prematurely after opening the database.
```

Comment: This looks like a less-detailed duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43398891/cannot-start-a-service-instance-in-openlink-virtuoso-universal-server and should probably be deleted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot start a service instance in OpenLink Virtuoso Universal Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43398891/cannot-start-a-service-instance-in-openlink-virtuoso-universal-server)