# Cannot start a service instance in OpenLink Virtuoso Universal Server

Tags: instance, startup, virtuoso

Our OpenLink Virtuoso Universal Server at the Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS.

When I run `./virtusoo-start.sh`, the service does not startup. and I got the message.

```
Starting Virtuoso instance in [database]
The VDBMS server process terminated prematurely
after opening the database.

***
*** ERROR: Could not start this Virtuoso Instance.
***
21:57:32 ./virtuoso() [0x5eb045]
21:57:32 ./virtuoso() [0x5f3c64]
21:57:32 ./virtuoso() [0x5f4aba]
21:57:32 ./virtuoso() [0x8eb806]
21:57:32 ./virtuoso() [0x8f776a]
21:57:32 ./virtuoso() [0x61db3f]
21:57:32 ./virtuoso() [0x410f6d]
21:57:32 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)  [0x7f00e9e4d7ed]
21:57:32 ./virtuoso(__gxx_personality_v0+0x2b9) [0x40b0e9]
21:57:32 GPF: blob.c:1345 Scheduling bad bl for delete at commit/rollback
***
*** Please fix the above issue(s) before trying again.
```

log info:

```
Thu Apr 13 2017

23:28:34 { Loading plugin 1: Type `plain', file `wikiv' in `../hosting'
23:28:34   WikiV version 0.6 from OpenLink Software
23:28:34   Support functions for WikiV collaboration tool
23:28:34   SUCCESS plugin 1: loaded from ../hosting/wikiv.so }
23:28:34 { Loading plugin 2: Type `plain', file `mediawiki' in `../hosting'
23:28:34   MediaWiki version 0.1 from OpenLink Software
23:28:34   Support functions for MediaWiki collaboration tool
23:28:34   SUCCESS plugin 2: loaded from ../hosting/mediawiki.so }
23:28:34 { Loading plugin 3: Type `plain', file `creolewiki' in `../hosting'
23:28:34   CreoleWiki version 0.1 from OpenLink Software
23:28:34   Support functions for CreoleWiki collaboration tool
23:28:34   SUCCESS plugin 3: loaded from ../hosting/creolewiki.so }
23:28:34 { Loading plugin 4: Type `plain', file `im' in `../hosting'
23:28:34   IM version 0.61 from OpenLink Software
23:28:34   Support functions for Image Magick 6.8.1
23:28:34   SUCCESS plugin 4: loaded from ../hosting/im.so }
23:28:34 { Loading plugin 5: Type `plain', file `wbxml2' in `../hosting'
23:28:34   WBXML2 version 0.9 from OpenLink Software
23:28:34   Support functions for WBXML2 0.9.2 Library
23:28:34   SUCCESS plugin 5: loaded from ../hosting/wbxml2.so }
23:28:34 { Loading plugin 6: Type `attach', file `libphp5.so' in `../hosting'
23:28:34   SUCCESS plugin 6: loaded from ../hosting/libphp5.so }
23:28:34 { Loading plugin 7: Type `Hosting', file `hosting_php.so' in `../hosting'
23:28:34   Hosting version 3202 from OpenLink Software
23:28:34   PHP engine version 5.3.21
23:28:34   SUCCESS plugin 7: loaded from ../hosting/hosting_php.so }
23:28:34 { Loading plugin 8: Type `plain', file `qrcode' in `../hosting'
23:28:34   QRcode version 0.1 from OpenLink Software
23:28:34   Support functions for ISO/IEC 18004:2006, using QR Code encoder (C) 2006 Kentaro Fukuchi <fukichi@megaui.net>
23:28:34   SUCCESS plugin 8: loaded from ../hosting/qrcode.so }
23:28:34 OpenLink Virtuoso Universal Server
23:28:34 Version 07.00.3202-pthreads for Linux as of Apr 23 2013
23:28:34 uses parts of OpenSSL, PCRE, Html Tidy
23:28:34 Registered to Industrial Technology Research Institute
23:28:34 Enterprise Edition license for 10 connections
23:28:34 Issued by OpenLink Software
23:28:34 Enabled Column Store Extension
23:28:34 Database version 3126
23:28:34 SQL Optimizer enabled (max 1000 layouts)
23:28:36 Compiler unit is timed at 0.000371 msec
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.AboriginalBySexCount' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.AboriginalBySex__Total' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.BandCount' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.Band__Total' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.CulturalCentersCount' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.CulturalCenters__Total' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.EthnicCount' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.Ethnic__Total' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.FeaturesStudioCount' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.FeaturesStudio__Total' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.FoodCount' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.Food__Total' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.HomeStayCount' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.HomeStay__Total' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.MuseumCount' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.Museum__Total' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.RestaurantCount' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.Restaurant__Total' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.SPACount' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.SPA__Total' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.SeasonalAnnouncementCount' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.SeasonalAnnouncement__Total' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.SeasonalFestivalsCount' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.SeasonalFestivals__Total' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.SeasonalIntroductionCount' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.SeasonalIntroduction__Total' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.TravelItineraryCount' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.TravelItinerary__Total' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.TribeApprovedCount' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.TribeApproved__Total' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.TribePopulationsCount' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.TribePopulations__Total' is owned by unknown  user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.cip__Total' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.CIP.cip_test__Total' is owned by unknown user 'CIP'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.mys5_lite.CIP__Total' is owned by unknown user 'mys5_lite'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.mys5_lite.DA_AboriginalLiteraryAnthologyCount' is owned by unknown user 'mys5_lite'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.mys5_lite_unicode.CIP__Total' is owned by unknown user 'mys5_lite_unicode'
23:28:36 View 'CIP.mys5_lite_unicode.DA_AboriginalLiteraryAnthologyCount' is owned by unknown user 'mys5_lite_unicode'
23:28:36 View 'Contest.IP.AboriginalBySexCount' is owned by unknown user 'IP'
23:28:36 View 'Contest.IP.BandCount' is owned by unknown user 'IP'
23:28:36 View 'Contest.IP.Contest1__Total' is owned by unknown user 'IP'
23:28:36 View 'Contest.IP.Contest__Total' is owned by unknown user 'IP'
23:28:36 View 'Contest.IP.CulturalCentersCount' is owned by unknown user 'IP'
23:28:36 View 'Contest.IP.EthnicCount' is owned by unknown user 'IP'
23:28:36 View 'Contest.IP.FeaturesStudioCount' is owned by unknown user 'IP'
23:28:36 View 'Contest.IP.FoodCount' is owned by unknown user 'IP'
23:28:36 View 'Contest.IP.HomeStayCount' is owned by unknown user 'IP'
23:28:36 View 'Contest.IP.MuseumCount' is owned by unknown user 'IP'
23:28:36 View 'Contest.IP.RestaurantCount' is owned by unknown user 'IP'
23:28:36 View 'Contest.IP.SPACount' is owned by unknown user 'IP'
23:28:36 View 'Contest.IP.TravelItineraryCount' is owned by unknown user 'IP'
23:28:36 View 'Contest.IP.TribeApprovedCount' is owned by unknown user 'IP'
23:28:36 View 'Contest.IP.TribePopulationsCount' is owned by unknown user 'IP'
23:28:36 Free blob page refd start = 12480 L=12480
23:28:36 ./virtuoso() [0x97f6f1]
23:28:36 ./virtuoso() [0x8d33d1]
23:28:36 ./virtuoso() [0x44da43]
23:28:36 ./virtuoso() [0x5e876e]
23:28:36 ./virtuoso() [0x5e9f1d]
23:28:36 ./virtuoso() [0x5ede85]
23:28:36 ./virtuoso() [0x5eaf8d]
23:28:36 ./virtuoso() [0x575963]
23:28:36 ./virtuoso() [0x576d15]
23:28:36 ./virtuoso() [0x5eb045]
23:28:36 ./virtuoso() [0x5f65c7]
23:28:36 ./virtuoso() [0x572ab0]
23:28:36 ./virtuoso() [0x57466a]
23:28:36 ./virtuoso() [0x5eaf75]
23:28:36 ./virtuoso() [0x5f3c64]
23:28:36 ./virtuoso() [0x5f489f]
23:28:36 ./virtuoso() [0x7f6a72]
23:28:36 ./virtuoso() [0x78797b]
23:28:36 ./virtuoso() [0x56f58c]
23:28:36 ./virtuoso() [0x577257]
23:28:36 ./virtuoso() [0x5eb045]
23:28:36 ./virtuoso() [0x5f3c64]
23:28:36 ./virtuoso() [0x5f4aba]
23:28:36 ./virtuoso() [0x8eb806]
23:28:36 ./virtuoso() [0x8f776a]
23:28:36 ./virtuoso() [0x61db3f]
23:28:36 ./virtuoso() [0x410f6d]
23:28:36 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed) [0x7fa77da9f7ed]
23:28:36 ./virtuoso(__gxx_personality_v0+0x2b9) [0x40b0e9]
23:28:36 GPF: blob.c:1345 Scheduling bad bl for delete at commit/rollback
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to run `Version 07.00.3202-pthreads for Linux as of Apr 23 2013`?

You'll get much better overall results with the latest stable release, ([`07.20.3217 as of April 2016`](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSNews#2016-04-24%20-%20Virtuoso%207.2.4%20Released,%20Open%20Source%20and%20Commercial%20Editions)), which you can [download here](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/download/).

That said, with the error you are getting, please check whether there is a `virtuoso.trx` file of more than 0 bytes.  If so, try renaming it (e.g., `virtuoso.trx.bad`) and restarting the server -- so that the `trx` file is not read at launch -- and see if that enables the server to start.

If the server starts, you can discard the renamed `trx` file -- *knowing that you will lose any transactions therein* -- or pursue more specific assistance through the Virtuoso Users mailing list, or an [OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp) as you're running Enterprise Edition (which I see you have already opened, simultaneously with posting here).

If not, then you may need to perform a `crash dump` and `restore` of the database, as [detailed in Virtuoso documentation](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/backup_recovery/#diagnosingrepairing).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! We have a line: "TransactionFile    = transaction/virtuoso20170413131059.trx " in virtuoso.ini file, so I rename the "virtuoso20170413131059.trx" . But It's not work .

Comment: I don't believe I advised renaming in that way...  Even if I had, "It's not work" is insufficient for me to provide further advice, and such conversation is frowned on at StackOverflow. Please follow up through [your existing OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp), as you are using the (Commercial) Enterprise Edition, and not the Open Source Edition.

Comment: Hi TallTed , Thank you for your help!!

"It's not work " means when I renamed the virtuoso.trx  and  transaction/virtuoso20170413131059.trx 
, but I still got the same message "....Scheduling bad bl for delete at commit/rollback"